# Can't recover time with TIMESTAMP on Hypersql

Tags: java, hsqldb

With Hypersql

I created a table like:

```
int result = stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE CACHED TABLE solicitudes ( "+
        "id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, extid VARCHAR(36), operacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, "+
        "imsi VARCHAR(20),msisdn VARCHAR(20),spid VARCHAR(20),prtb VARCHAR(20),imsiNuevo VARCHAR(20),"
        + "msisdnNuevo VARCHAR(20), fec_creacion TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, fec_lstUpdate TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,"
        + "estado VARCHAR(2),etapa VARCHAR(30),subetapa VARCHAR(30), reintentos INT,"
        + "codresp VARCHAR(20),descresp VARCHAR(100), "+
        "PRIMARY KEY (id));");
```

Where fec_creacion is

```
fec_creacion TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
```

Then I inserted a row like:

```
String strSQL="INSERT INTO solicitudes VALUES ( "
        + " '"+id+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getIdext()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getOperacion()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getImsi()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getMsisdn()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getSpid()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getPrtb()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getImsiNuevo()+"',"
        + " '"+sol.getMsisdnNuevo()+"',"
        + " CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , NULL,'-','-','-',0,"
        + " '"+r.getCodigo()+"',"
        + " '"+r.getDescripcion()+"');";
st.executeUpdate(strSQL);
```

I guess that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP put the DATE and Time and Timezone in the field "fec_creacion"

Then, I recover the data from the table with:

```
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("Select id,extid,operacion,fec_creacion,fec_lstUpdate,estado,etapa,subetapa,reintentos FROM SOLICITUDES ORDER BY fec_creacion desc LIMIT 5");
while(result.next()){
    Date fec = result.getDate("fec_creacion");          
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    String sfec=dateFormat.format(fec);
    System.out.println("  fecc="+sfec);
}
```

But the log show fecc without the time

```
fecc=2017-09-25T00:00:00-03:00
```

I tested the pattern of SimpleDateFormat in another part of the code and is OK.

Answer (score 0):

My error was

```
Date fec = result.getDate("fec_creacion");
```

The correct way is

```
Timestamp fecx = result.getTimestamp("fec_creacion");   
Date fec = new Date(fecx.getTime());
```